# Best way to use type classes with list parametrized with some base class, abstract class or trait

Tags: scala, inheritance, typeclass

I think it would be easier to describe a problem with concrete example. Suppose I have have `Fruit` class hierarchy and `Show` type class:

```
trait Fruit
case class Apple extends Fruit
case class Orange extends Fruit

trait Show[T] {
    def show(target: T): String
}

object Show { 
    implicit object AppleShow extends Show[Apple] {
        def show(apple: Apple) = "Standard apple"
    }

    implicit object OrangeShow extends Show[Orange] {
        def show(orange: Orange) = "Standard orange"
    }
}

def getAsString[T](target: T)(implicit s: Show[T]) = s show target
```

I also have list of fruits that I would like to show to the user using `Show` *(this is my main goal in this question)*:

```
val basket = List[Fruit](Apple(), Orange())

def printList[T](list: List[T])(implicit s: Show[T]) = 
    list foreach (f => println(s show f))

printList(basket)
```

This will not compile because `List` is parametrized with `Fruit` and I have not defined any `Show[Fruit]`. **What is the best way to achieve my goal using type classes?**

I tried to find solution for this problem, but unfortunately have not found any nice one yet. It's not enough to know `s` in `printList` function - somehow it needs to know `Show[T]` for each element of the list. This means, that in order to be able to make this, we need some run-time mechanism in addition to the compile-time one. This gave me an idea of some kind of run-time dictionary, that knows, how to find correspondent `Show[T]` at run-time.

Implementation of implicit `Show[Fruit]`can serve as such dictionary:

```
implicit object FruitShow extends Show[Fruit] {
    def show(f: Fruit) = f match {
        case a: Apple => getAsString(a)
        case o: Orange => getAsString(o)
    }
}
```

And actually very similar approach can be found in haskell. As an example, we can look at `Eq` implementation for `Maybe`:

```
instance (Eq m) => Eq (Maybe m) where  
    Just x == Just y = x == y  
    Nothing == Nothing = True  
    _ == _ = False
```

The big problem with this solution, is that if I will add new subclass of `Fruit` like this:

```
case class Banana extends Fruit

object Banana {
    implicit object BananaShow extends Show[Banana] {
        def show(banana: Banana) = "New banana"
    }
}
```

and will try to print my basket:

```
val basket = List[Fruit](Apple(), Orange(), Banana())

printList(basket)
```

then `scala.MatchError` would be thrown because my dictionary does not know anything about bananas yet. Of course, I can provide updated dictionary in some context that knows about bananas:

```
implicit object NewFruitShow extends Show[Fruit] {
    def show(f: Fruit) = f match {
        case b: Banana => getAsString(b)
        case otherFruit => Show.FruitShow.show(otherFruit)
    }
}
```

But this solution is far from perfect. Just imagine that some other library provides another fruit with it's own version of dictionary. It will just conflict with `NewFruitShow` if I try to use them together.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

---

#### Update

As @Eric noticed, there is one more solution described here: [forall in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213676/forall-in-scala) . It's really looks very interesting. But I see one problem with this solution.

If I use `ShowBox`, then it will remember concrete type class during it's creation time. So I generally building list with objects and correspondent type classes (so dictionary in present in the list). From the other hand, scala has very nice feature: I can drop new implicits in the current scope and they will override defaults. So I can define alternative string representation  for the classes like:

```
object CompactShow { 
    implicit object AppleCompactShow extends Show[Apple] {
        def show(apple: Apple) = "SA"
    }

    implicit object OrangeCompactShow extends Show[Orange] {
        def show(orange: Orange) = "SO"
    }
}
```

and then just import it in current scope with `import CompactShow._`. In this case `AppleCompactShow` and `OrangeCompactShow` object would be implicitly used instead of defaults defined in the companion object of `Show`. And as you can guess, list creation and printing happens in different places. If I will use `ShowBox`, than most probably I will capture default instances of type class. I would like to capture them at the last possible moment - the moment when I call `printList`, because I even don't know, whether my `List[Fruit]` will ever be shown or how it would be shown, in the code that creates it.

Comment: I think that this very question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213676/forall-in-scala

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for the replay. I updated my question - seems that this solution raises another problem.

Answer (score 7):

The most obvious answer is to use a `sealed trait Fruit` and a `Show[Fruit]`. That way your pattern matches will complain at compile time when the match is not exhaustive. Of course, adding a new kind of `Fruit` in an external library will not be possible, but this is inherent in the nature of things. This is the "[expression problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_problem)".

You could also stick the `Show` instance on the Fruit trait:

```
trait Fruit { self =>
  def show: Show[self.type]
}

case class Apple() extends Fruit { self =>
  def show: Show[self.type] = showA
}
```

Or, you know, stop subtyping and use type classes instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and please excuse me for the late answer. In most cases I can keep classes sealed, but sometimes I would like to give users ability to have their own implementations of my traits. Of course, I can stick the `Show` instance on the Fruit trait, but it's exactly what I want to avoid by using type classes. I also thought about implementing everything with type classes, but I believe, that it will not solve the problem I described (please correct me if I'm wrong). Can you provide an example, that uses only type classes and solves the problem I described?

Comment: Have a look at a paper called "Data Types a la Carte". It's the solution to your problem, but it sacrifices genericity. It is incredibly difficult to implement that approach in Scala.